# Integration with Amplify JS and Cognito in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, amazon-cognito

I have been trying the Authentication using Amplify JS and able to log in and Change password when `user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED'` and I have `componentDidMount()` in my Approuter where all the routes site. when navigated to change password screen `componentDidMount()` is not calling.

**condition in login:**

```
 if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {

     this.props.history.push('/ChangePassword')}
```

**In Approuter:**

```
async componentDidMount() {

    try {
      const session = await Auth.currentSession();
      this.setAuthStatus(true);
      console.log(session);
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();debugger;
      this.setUser(user);
    } catch(error) {
      if (error !== 'No current user') {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

**change password:**

```
  let user =  Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();

  Auth.changePassword(
        user, 
        values.tempPassword,              
        values.newPassword

      ).then(user => {
        // at this time the user is logged in if no MFA required
        console.log(user);
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

**Expected:**

1. User has to be Cognito object and change password should update and confirm the user.

**Actual:**

User.session() is not a function.

Comment: `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` is implemented (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2602), you need use callback.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample in Angular (may be same code for React):

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: result => {
        console.log(err);
        ...
    },
    onFailure: err => {
      console.log(err);
      ...
    },
    newPasswordRequired: (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) => {
      subscriber.error({
        reason: 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD',
        user: {
          username: user
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: I am currently using Amplify JS for the Auth Process.

Comment: @HemanthBatchu, your Amplify JS is not `amazon-cognito-identity-js` ?

Comment: @HemanthBatchu, if you use `aws-amplify-react`, here's how they test this particular case: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/aws-amplify-react/__tests__/Auth/RequireNewPassword-test.js